# How to check duplicates records in a folder/file on HDFS

Tags: duplicates, hdfs

From time to time we receive client data that might contains duplicates and we want to know that in advance, the client data is typically in txt or csv format but will be uploaded to HDFS and then become visible to us, how can we check the file and ensure any possible duplicates records can be picked up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution is indeed quite simple:

```
var df = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> input_file, "header" -> has_header, "delimiter" -> delimiter, "inferSchema" -> infer_schema))
val df_distinct = df.dropDuplicates();
```